# Why could the loading of a GWT-App lead to an Parse error, if loaded at an iOs Device in Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gwt, ios4

I have a GWT Application, which loads fine if the device is hold in landscape. If I turn it to portrait-mode the application will *sometimes* fail to load.

A SyntaxError: Parse error is shown in the console of the browser. If I reload the app, it *may* load fine.

[image: Screenshot of the console.log]

I am using gwt 2.2. I am not sure, if the bug appeard in GWT 2.1.1.

What can cause the mobile safari to fail loading the *.nocache.html only in portrait-mode and only sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know why this Problem can be solved like this, but as I changed the Linker to the following code, the problem disappeared.

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.CrossSiteIframeLinker" />
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```